# loading a .dylib library to matlab

Tags: matlab, gcc, loadlibrary

I am trying to add a simple library to matlab using the "loadlibrary" function. I first try linking the gcc compiler to matlab with mex -setup and get this:

The options files available for mex are:

1: /Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/bin/mexopts.sh : 
      Template Options file for building gcc MEX-files

0: Exit with no changes

So I just chose 1 and continued. I then received this message:

---

Warning: The MATLAB C and Fortran API has changed to support MATLAB 
           variables with more than 2^32-1 elements.  In the near future 
           you will be required to update your code to utilize the new 
           API. You can find more information about this at: 
           http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/bsflnue-1.html
           Building with the -largeArrayDims option enables the new API.

---

after this i type in:
loadlibrary('Samplelib.dylib','Samplelib.h')

Error using loadlibrary (line 419)
Failed to preprocess the input file.
 Output from preprocessor is:/bin/bash: gcc-4.2: command not found

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Anish, did our answers help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are using matlab on mac, true? You need to install gcc first, before you will be able to proceed. Try Xcode - you need **gcc-4.2** because it is hard-coded in the mentioned mexopts.sh How to install it depends on your MacOS version, but google xcode, you will find plenty of links.

Answer (score 0):

The first "Warning" is just to tell you that the C API is now better than ever because it supports a huge number of elements, but will need to be enabled using a new option in later versions of Matlab.  Long story short, you don't care.  The next error about gcc-4.2 means that the gcc 4.2 compiler is not on your path.  If you do a:

```
    [s1,r1] = system('which gcc')
    disp( r1 )
    disp( s1 )
    [s2,r2] = system('which gcc-4.2')
    disp( r2 )
    disp( s2 )
```

Likely, one or both will come back with an error.  Make sure the gcc compiler is on your `PATH` environment variable.

Like againor says, you'll need to have the compiler installed as well. :-)

Comment: hey thanks for the quick reply. So I'm pretty sure I have gcc version 4.2, if I type gcc -v in terminal, I get :
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
I'm not really sure how to go about adding it to my path variable.

Thanks again for your help!